# Edit Page blank

Tags: wp-editor

I have been given the task of looking after our office website which is a WordPress website. I have been creating and maintaining websites for over 25 years and have used WordPress, but it was a long time ago. However, when I try to edit pages the editor is blank with 0 word count. 
This appears to be a common problem, so what causes this and is there a simple fix for it? I have tried some of the advice given by others but nothing appears to work. I have used a number of different browsers too.
Considering I have other things to do and have wasted some hours on this, my cure would be to simply dump WordPress, retrieve the URL and host a new site online which I have complete control over. However, my boss has asked me to speak to you first. So, can anyone help with this extremely annoying problem?

Comment: This is nonstandard behaviour, so that leaves us here guessing as well. Are the pages visible on the frontend? Is WP updated to the latest version? And the plugins? Is it possible to make new pages? If yes, can they be edited? Do you have admin access or less capabilities? And so on...